# Changing document.domain to completely other domain

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prove that changing document.domain can be used only for cross scripting on the same upper level domain. For example if i will try to change document.domain to "google.com" on page which is located on www.test.com I will get a security exception in FF. Does anybody know where to locate an official proof of that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out : [developer.mozilla.org/same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Here is an excerpt from the site:

> There is one exception to the same
> origin rule. A script can set the
> value of document.domain to a suffix
> of the current domain. If it does so,
> the shorter domain is used for
> subsequent origin checks. For example,
> assume a script in the document at
> http://store.company.com/dir/other.html
> executes the following statement:
>
> document.domain = "company.com";
>
> After
> that statement executes, the page
> would pass the origin check with
> http://company.com/dir/page.html.
> However, by the same reasoning,
> **company.com could not set
> document.domain to othercompany.com.**