# Uploadify "Uncaught Call to StartUpload failed" when used in Facebook Canvas app on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, flash, uploadify

I have implemented the standard Flash version of the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) [jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/205/) within a canvas app on Facebook.

The upload is working perfectly fine in Firefox. But when I try to start an upload in Chrome or IE, it fails with this message in the console:

> `Uncaught Call to StartUpload failed`

For those not familiar with Facebook canvas apps, it's PHP pages running within an iframe in Facebook which might be leading to this problem - though it doesn't work when run outside of a frame either.

I'm also getting these errors in the Chrome console:

> `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://apps.facebook.com/[app name]/[page name]/ from frame with URL https://[app domain]/[page path]. The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.`

Any ideas what might be happening? I've already tried setting up a **crossdomain.xml** for Flash with no success.

Comment: i just got the same problem and found out that the error occurs whenever i try to include swfobject.js. even without any other code and just the swfobject.js included in the header, the error comes up, only in chrome.

Comment: For anyone who may be wondering, I never found a solution to this, and for the project it was being used on, we moved away from using Uploadify, so unfortunately I can't offer any more useful information.

Comment: seems browsers flash player problem. can u try upgrading this.

Answer (score 1):

According to another thread [Changing document.domain to completely other domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600709/changing-document-domain-to-completely-other-domain), it is possible that change domain to the suffix of current domain.

If the "[app domain]" can be changed, you can try change [app domain] to "https://[app domain].apps.facebook.com/" and run the javascript from iframe page when iframe is loaded

```
document.domain = 'facebook.com';
```

But not sure whether there are any issues of adding another domain as suffix (is it legal?).

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue a long time ago with facebook and crossdomain, did you try

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

on your php file?

Answer (score 1):

1.-try edit your urls in your api settings, as name_api_to_download.domain.com or domain.com, and use only ssl subdomain or domain true

2.-use ajax request(post or get) preferer to download files and not iframes, because you use parent iframe api, and it not is accesible

3.-use in name_api_to_download a header valid(as a MIME type is application/pdf )