# Object.defineProperty breaks chrome window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So, I wanted to set in one part of the page that document.domain property can't be set, so I used this call:

```
Object.defineProperty( document, "domain", {
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

And later in the page I have the call that just changes `writable` attribute to true:

```
Object.defineProperty( document, "domain", {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

However, immediately after setting it to true, my chrome window breaks and I get the blue screen with the message:  `Aw snap! Something went wrong while displaying the webpage`. What's wrong here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600709/changing-document-domain-to-completely-other-domain

Comment: I don't have a problem with the origin, because I didn't even changed document.domain, just having those 2 calls will break the web page

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, why would you want it anyway?

Comment: Hmm, can reproduce here. I'd consider filing a bug with the Chromium project after checking if any other properties also have the same behaviour. Firefox has no issues with this code.